# My question got deleted by a moderator - I want to appeal and know why my post has been deleted

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions, moderators

I am new here, so I don't have much experience here but still I would like to know why the moderator deleted my question in Stack Overflow. But I don't know how to appeal. Someone said that we can appeal in here. Link is given below.

Link to my Stack Overflow question:
[How do I link to another HTML file with a button using Tailwind?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72012664/18926607)

Comment: [Screenshot of the deleted question for users who cannot see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZItBD.png)

Comment: You can custom mod flag your own post while it's deleted to ask, although given the screenshot it's kind of expected.

Comment: Sorry, your questions is of very poor quality and will never be excepted as it is on stackoverflow. You appear to have done absolutely no research effort. You did not provide source code. It's not clear what your problem is. Folks at stackoverflow can't help you answer your question in your current form. Please be specific with what issues your are having.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine OP earned the Citizen Patrol badge on SO shortly before posting this, so I assume they already did raise a flag of some kind.

Comment: Why doesn't "BossProgrammer7829" exist here? Was a separate account used on MSE? Or is it a fault of the migration system?

Comment: @PeterMortensen [Everything shows up correctly on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1185722/bossprogrammer7829), so probably something in the migration system.

Comment: @PeterMortensen no, it is [definitely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18926607/bossprogrammer7829?tab=profile) this one. However, it's weird as it appears to not have a Meta profile - something must've gone wrong during migration indeed.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine IIRC you only have a meta profile _if you've actually been on the meta site_. Chances are they've just never visited meta and so their profile hasn't been created.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine hmm, might be it. Admittedly, I am not an SME on migration, but I thought that a meta migration would hook the account on main. Wonder if what we see is intentional.

Comment: That's correct; Meta accounts are not created by default. If the user creates an account on Meta, it should link with this question.

Comment: Hey , I made my account on Stackoverflow

Comment: Please read this if you can't ask new questions: **[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583)**

Answer (score 31):

Your question was flagged by another user as "spam", and the moderator who initially reviewed that flag agreed with it. Upon review, I cannot determine why either person thought your question was spam. I presume it had something to do with its [initial revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72012664/1) being a very low-quality post with a prominent link (which was, in fact, to an image).

Either way, it certainly is not spam under Stack Overflow's definition. Therefore, I have to disagree with the deletion, which I've now overridden (i.e., undeleted your question) and cleared the spam flag.

However, although your question isn't spam and doesn't need to be immediately deleted, your question still doesn't meet [our minimum requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a question. You are asking for help with a problem on a website, but you have not included any [code that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As such, I have closed your question, pending any edits you can make to improve it.

After you submit an edit that adds the code, you can indicate that the edit resolved the problem(s) which led to the question being closed. That will put the question into review queue, where other users can vote to re-open it (if your edits have, in fact, fixed the problem).

---

Independent of this specific situation, if you want to appeal the deletion of a post by a moderator, you have two options, both of which you have already availed yourself of:

1. Raise a custom moderator flag ("in need of moderator intervention"), which gives you a textbox where you can plead your case and ask for a second review. This does work, especially where a mistake was made. Unfortunately, the character limit for replies is very short, so if the deletion was *not* a mistake, we moderators will have a very hard time explaining the problem to you.

   Which brings us to…
2. Post on Meta, appealing for a review. You *almost* did this right, with one nitpick. You posted on the global Stack Exchange Meta site (Meta Stack Exchange), which covers the entire network. For an issue specific to a single site, you really need to post on that site's Meta, which for Stack Overflow would be https://meta.stackoverflow.com/. If you ask on the right Meta site, the moderators of that site are sure to see your question. (In this case, you were lucky that this was brought to my attention, and I've also flagged it to request migration to Meta Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Regarding spam: one could argue that this is a camouflaged advertisement for their own blog with the hope that it isn't recognized as such when they don't link to the blog itself but use an image where the blog name is mentioned.

Comment: That seems like a *major* stretch, @Tom. I'm one of the mods most sympathetic to spam flags on low-effort "here's a link to my site, debug it" questions, but this doesn't even have a link to the site, as you said. I'm just not seeing any angle from which this could be reasonably considered spam.

Comment: It is a bit of a stretch, I agree, but this _could_ (just an assumption) be a reason why it got deleted as spam. And when I think about it, using just an image of the site name "feels" like the next step of evading spam detection. First, bots wrote blatant spam message, then they evolved to hiding spam in a fake question ("I have a problem on my site ....") and the next step can be hiding the site name in an image to prevent automatic detection, like emails are protected with images to prevent web crawlers from reading them.

Comment: What do we do then about the fact that this question has found itself deleted in spite of the advice you provided?  I think that editing it is the right *saying* but deleting this post feels like we're not going to give the OP a chance - we've moved the goalposts literally while we're telling them where the goalposts are.

Comment: Fixing what made it look like spam... doesn't necessarily fix all the other problems that may exist.

Comment: We shake our fists in the air angrily, @Makoto. Seriously, WTF?

Comment: FWIW it was me that flagged it as spam, for the precise reason mentioned by @Tom. Might be an innocent mistake, but seemed to me as a promotion with extra steps